# Onomatopoeia for foxes

Tags: onomatopoeia

["What does the fox say?" Onomatopoeia, and Alien Languages](http://talktoyouniverse.blogspot.com.au/2013/09/what-does-fox-say-onomatopoeia-and.html) claims there's no onomatopoeia for foxes:

> But you don't find fox onomatopoeia in this context. Foxes tend to do
>   one of two things: either they are silent, or they speak like humans
>   do. It's certainly a testament to the fox's slyness that it's
>   attributed with human speech, which fits quite well with its trickster
>   qualities (and of course there are many myths that have the fox
>   transforming itself into human shape, too).

The article goes on to cite a [Wired article](http://www.wired.com/underwire/2013/09/what-does-the-fox-say-ylvis/) claiming that some of the sounds made in the Ylvis song [The Fox (What Does the Fox Say?)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jofNR_WkoCE), such as "Chacha-chacha-chacha-chow", are accurate, but it doesn't indicate that they are commonly used onomatopoeia.

Are there any commonly used onomatopoeia for foxes in English?

Comment: Not any commonly used ones, no. Foxes do not feature much in English speakers' mythological life, perhaps because they no longer feature at all in their actual life. Most North Americans, for instance, have never seen a fox in person, and wouldn't recognize it as a fox if they did. Hence there is no need of onomatopoeic expression for foxes, any more than there is for armadillos or aardvarks.

Comment: onomatopoeia is for sounds things make. Not the thing itself.

Comment: @JohnLawler Brer Fox, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_fictional_foxes

Comment: @JohnLawler  In the last ten years or so, foxes have gone from storybook creatures to frequent roadkill in my neck of the woods (Philadelphia burbs). I see foxes several times a week and hear their strange bark in the crepuscular hours every day.

Comment: (Urban) foxes are everywhere in Bristol, England!  It's sort of a fox thing hereabouts to be discrete - seen out of the corner of your eye and rarely heard.  No 'typical' onamatopoeic foxy utterances come to mind.

Comment: The article seems to be making a literary or cultural point not a linguistic one - foxes in stories do one of two things. (Incidentally I'm surprised that Americans never see foxes because they're very common in urban Britain as Dan says, but I guess the US has other animals like raccoons, opossoms, or bears that eat from bins.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Short answer:** No - [which is why the Ylvis song is funny](https://youtu.be/jofNR_WkoCE).

You can make one up that matches the sound they actually make or use the word "Bark"

**Longer answer:**

Here are more examples of fox sounds from a [Viral Video: What The Fox Actually Sounds Like](https://www.livescience.com/39478-what-foxes-sound-like.html) and

[Fox Calls](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J6NuhlibHsM):

- Alarm bark
- Vixen's scream
- Gekkering
- Howl

Literature seems to favour *bark* which can be considered a weak onomatopoeia (BARK, BARK BARK does sound a bit like a dog)

> I heard the foxes as they ranged over the snow crust, in moonlight nights, in search of a partridge or other game, barking like forest dogs...
> <sub>Thoreau</sub>

---

> At night when I slept under an oak tree in the yard, when the white clouds scudded across a blue night sky of spring — it was then I heard the foxes bark on the high mountain top. They barked for me. <sub>Jesse Stuart</sub>

---

> I heard the foxes howling near the house these two nights back. They always herald a death in our family. <sub>Sean O'Callaghan</sub>

---

> I heard the fox kit begin to vocalize in a high-pitched, laughing yodel. <sub>John Ulanich</sub>

Comment: Verbs associated with animals sounds are not onomatopoeia. Perhaps you might clarify that.

Comment: ??? _Common onomatopoeias include animal noises such as oink, meow (or miaow), roar, and chirp._ The pig oinked, the bird chirped

Comment: woof, yes. bark, not really.

Comment: "No - hence the joke"... the joke?

Comment: ["What does the fox say?"](https://youtu.be/jofNR_WkoCE) and the [article mentioned in the question](http://talktoyouniverse.blogspot.com/2013/09/what-does-fox-say-onomatopoeia-and.html)