# What it the morphological classification of the ending -ump?

Tags: morphology

Can someone tell me how to classify the morpheme -ump, such as can be combined with lump,slump, bump, etc.  (It's for a research I'm doing on onomatopoeia.) thanks

Comment: [*-Ump*](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/-ump.pdf) is not a morpheme; it's a phonestheme. It's [a **rime**](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/rimecoherence.pdf), one of the two varieties of phonestheme in assonance-rime sound symbolism; the other variety is **assonance**, like the [/kl-/ in _clump_](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/kl-chart.pdf) or the [/st-/ in _stump_](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/style.pdf). More resources are [available here](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/monobib.pdf). Oh, btw, this is not onomatopoeia -- that's only about names for noises -- this is much broader.

Comment: Why two questions?

Comment: If you are interested in onomatopoeia maybe you'd like to look at this question [bleat](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/170536/do-onomatopoeic-words-lose-their-onomatopoeic-character)

Comment: Would this type of question be more appropriate on linguistics.stackexchange.com?

Comment: Turns out [I've already answered this one before](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/96637/15299).

Comment: Thanks guys, wish me luck for my conference presentation... I'm arguing that there is a sound-sense correspondence among several of the words that rhyme with "-ump"; ie words like "lump", "bump", "clump", refer somehow to a "rounded mass"...(I'm the solids, liquids, and gases person).. with "bump" referring to the hardest solids (begins with an occlusive); "lump" being a softer solid, possibly within a thick liquid. And, with "clump" referring to a roundish (maybe) mass riddled through with fibrous matter.  As for "onomatopoeia", I use a second def, as "words that imitate their sense"

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a morpheme or common word element in the three words.
In my view ( different from etymonline) "lump" is connected with German Klumpen (with the same meaning as lump), "to slump" is connected with German plumpsen ( if you place the German s at the end in the position of the first English p you get slump), and "to bump" is connected to German bumsen (similar meaning). I can't discover that the three words contain a common word element.

Onomatopoeia means words that imitate sound. "lump" has nothing to do with sound.
German plumpsen can be called a sound-imitating word, but after the s has taken the position of p at the front to give slump it is questionable whether "to slump" is sound-imitation.

I think "bump" is the only word where most people would agree that it is onomatopoetic.

Well, I think, the three words don't give much as to research in morphemes or sound-imitation.