# Where do all the fox references come from?

Tags: etymology, expressions, history

A person can be `crazy like a fox`, and attractive lady is `foxy` or even `a fox`, an old book might have `foxing`, to outsmart someone is to `outfox` them, if you are confused you are `foxed`, and there are probably even more examples that don't immediately spring to mind.

Where does this obsession with foxes come from?

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, there isn't *enough* obsession with foxes.

Comment: And we still do not know what the fox says...

Comment: @mplungjan Sure we do—[it gekkers](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/144083/what-does-the-fox-say)!

Comment: Ah, yeah. "Gek, gek, gek" - hmm, does not roll off the tongue like "Moo, Miauw, Woof, Baah" ;)

Comment: Don't forget _foxfire_ (that weird glow of decaying vegetative matter in a forest) and _Firefox_ (that endlessly updating browser).

Comment: @Erik Kowal Do you want hunting unbanned?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - That depends on which way round the unbanning takes effect. For instance, I think Tony Blair should be hunted to extinction. By foxes.

Comment: Obsessed [in comparison to what](http://www.usingenglish.com/reference/idioms/cat/10.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The  [Fox](http://www.k-state.edu/wwparent/programs/hero/hero-des-fox.htm) used as a metaphor has a long history, the following extract explains why:

> - The fox has a long history of magic and cunning associated with it. The Indians of central California regarded the silver fox as a culture-hero while in Siberia the crafty messenger from Hell, who lured the legendary hero underground, was often depicted in the shape of a black fox.
> - In the orient, it was believed that foxes were capable of assuming human form. In the Ch'u Kingdom of China foxes were believed to possess plenty of vital force because they live in the earth and are therefore close to the generative powers of the Earth itself.
> - The Cherokees invoke fox medicine to prevent frostbite, and Hopi shamans always wear fox skins for their healing rites. The Choctaw saw fox as the protector of the family unity. Apaches credited fox for sticking its tail fur into the flame and stealing fire for humans.

Associations

> - The fox is associated with working to blend in with the surroundings, to come and go unnoticed, and to move silently. According to both Native American and Druidic belief, fox medicine involves adaptability, cunning, observation, integration, diplomacy and swiftness of thought and action.

As for the use of [Fox](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=fox&allowed_in_frame=0) as a metaphor in the English language: (from Etymonline)

> - Metaphoric extension to "clever person" was in late Old English. Meaning "sexually attractive woman" is from 1940s; but foxy in this sense is recorded from 1895. A fox-tail was anciently one of the badges of a fool (late 14c.).

Comment: Whole books were written about the misdeeds and cunning of the Fox, in French about Maître Renard and Goethe wrote a very funny tale in verses about Reinecke Fuchs.

Comment: Fascinating, but how do the Californian, Siberian, Chinese and Cherokee associations inform English usage?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth -The extract shows that the fox has always exerted  a certain inflence on different cultures. These traditions have affected the usage of many languages (fox as a methaphors is  present not only in the English language). As for the early usage of fox as a methaphor see the etymonline link I provided in the answer!